# How to make a clear x icon within top right of textarea on focus

Tags: jquery, html, textarea

I am using bootstrap 3 and I would like to know how to make a textarea with a clear x icon that appear when user is on focus just like youtube does its comment textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Use some jQuery focus/focusout to show/hide the icon. You could use a background image for that. 
http://api.jquery.com/focus/

And attach a click event, which checks where in the box the user clicked. 
For example, if it was between 0 and 10px from the right, you could assume they clicked your icon.

Code should be something like this:

```
$('#element').focus(function() {
     $(this).css('background', 'red');
});

$('#element').focusout(function() {
     $(this).css('background', 'white');
});

$('#element').click(function(e) {
    if (($(this).width()-(e.pageX - $(this).position().left)) < 10){
        alert('clear textbox');
    }
});
```

Or better, chained code:

```
$('#element').focus(function() {
     $(this).css('background', 'red');
}).focusout(function() {
     $(this).css('background', 'white');
}).click(function(e) {
    if (($(this).width()-(e.pageX - $(this).position().left)) < 20){
        $(this).val('');
    }
});
```